# mkdocs meta-tags for opengraph

Tags: html, meta-tags, read-the-docs, share-open-graph

I would like to have an image preview when sharing links to my mkdocs documentation, hosted and built by RTD. I need to override the HTML header of the site and add an open graph protocol.

After some investigation, I found a few resources on HTML overrides for the Material theme:
https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/meta-tags/
https://rohancragg.co.uk/writing/social-media-sharing/
A plug-in like this for sphinx would be ideal:
https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-opengraph

Unfortunately, I am using mkdocs and the readthedocs theme for my documentation and apparently, this does not fully support the meta extension:

Here is what I did:
I was able to add the extension and link a main.html override containing the open graph protocol. The link-sharing worked just fine! Unfortunately, now all pages in my doc just render in white. I don't get an error message in the built log (below), or I am overlooking something.
Looking at the raw html, I can see that the header now only contains the opengraph protocol and the body is empty:

```
<html data-lt-installed="true">
    <head>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website">
        <meta property="og:title" content="Faceit Documentation - Overview">
        <meta property="og:description" content="Faceit - Auto-Rig IPhoneX Shape Keys (Blendshapes) - Performance Capture for ANY Character!">
        <meta property="og:url" content="https://faceit-doc.readthedocs.io/">
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Essentially, I am wondering if there is a way to add meta-tags to the header in the readthedocs theme, analog to what is possible in the Material theme.

Here is the built log from readthedocs:

```
Read the Docs build information
Build id: 14195757
Project: faceit-doc
Version: v2
Commit: 600a315069246da2bb770304f88cadb6ca3d6426
Date: 2021-07-08T14:56:54.817314Z
State: finished
Success: True

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:56:55.980380Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:56:59.243670Z, duration: 3, exit-code: 0
git clone --no-single-branch --depth 50 https://gitlab.com/f-brar/faceit_doc.git .
Cloning into '.'...

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:56:59.398910Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:56:59.981942Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git checkout --force origin/v2
Note: checking out 'origin/v2'.

You are in a 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you to create, you may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 600a315 restore overrides

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:00.159294Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:00.223086Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git clean -d -f -f


[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:00.340941Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:00.405472Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git rev-parse HEAD
600a315069246da2bb770304f88cadb6ca3d6426

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:01.720061Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:05.558422Z, duration: 3, exit-code: 0
python3.7 -mvirtualenv /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2
Using base prefix '/home/docs/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9'
New python executable in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:05.703925Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:06.743957Z, duration: 1, exit-code: 0
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir pip setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (21.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (57.1.0)

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:06.877227Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:16.815885Z, duration: 9, exit-code: 0
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir mock==1.0.1 pillow==5.4.1 alabaster>=0.7,<0.8,!=0.7.5 commonmark==0.8.1 recommonmark==0.5.0 mkdocs
Collecting mock==1.0.1
  Downloading mock-1.0.1.zip (861 kB)
Collecting pillow==5.4.1
  Downloading Pillow-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.0 MB)
Collecting alabaster!=0.7.5,<0.8,>=0.7
  Downloading alabaster-0.7.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting commonmark==0.8.1
  Downloading commonmark-0.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting recommonmark==0.5.0
  Downloading recommonmark-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting mkdocs
  Downloading mkdocs-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (6.3 MB)
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting sphinx>=1.3.1
  Downloading Sphinx-4.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.9 MB)
Collecting docutils>=0.11
  Downloading docutils-0.17.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (575 kB)
Collecting sphinxcontrib-applehelp
  Downloading sphinxcontrib_applehelp-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (121 kB)
Collecting Pygments>=2.0
  Downloading Pygments-2.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.0 MB)
Collecting snowballstemmer>=1.1
  Downloading snowballstemmer-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
Collecting imagesize
  Downloading imagesize-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.8 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.5.0
  Downloading requests-2.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting Jinja2>=2.3
  Downloading Jinja2-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting sphinxcontrib-devhelp
  Downloading sphinxcontrib_devhelp-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
Collecting sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp
  Downloading sphinxcontrib_htmlhelp-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
Collecting sphinxcontrib-qthelp
  Downloading sphinxcontrib_qthelp-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (90 kB)
Collecting packaging
  Downloading packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting sphinxcontrib-jsmath
  Downloading sphinxcontrib_jsmath-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from sphinx>=1.3.1->recommonmark==0.5.0) (57.1.0)
Collecting sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml
  Downloading sphinxcontrib_serializinghtml-1.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Collecting babel>=1.3
  Downloading Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
Collecting pytz>=2015.7
  Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (31 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2021.5.30-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting idna<3,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting chardet<5,>=3.0.2
  Downloading chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting mergedeep>=1.3.4
  Downloading mergedeep-1.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=3.10
  Downloading importlib_metadata-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting Markdown>=3.2.1
  Downloading Markdown-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting PyYAML>=3.10
  Downloading PyYAML-5.4.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (636 kB)
Collecting click>=3.3
  Downloading click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting ghp-import>=1.0
  Downloading ghp-import-2.0.1.tar.gz (11 kB)
Collecting pyyaml-env-tag>=0.1
  Downloading pyyaml_env_tag-0.1-py3-none-any.whl (3.9 kB)
Collecting watchdog>=2.0
  Downloading watchdog-2.1.3-py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (75 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.8.1
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (227 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Downloading zipp-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.7 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.4
  Downloading typing_extensions-3.10.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting six>=1.5
  Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mock, ghp-import, future
  Building wheel for mock (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for mock (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for mock: filename=mock-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=23772 sha256=ecc0dc7eb6efdc5f70233fc29fce5f4f940a567cfcb02b520f0a7cf59b57abf7
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-d_w0zttj/wheels/7a/94/b1/0fdc5339a5bd487a5cc15421ec200d9ba3e2aa7190e4a727f1
  Building wheel for ghp-import (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for ghp-import (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for ghp-import: filename=ghp_import-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl size=11028 sha256=65be8307c2e39b5d2fa3d7d13e268eb887939ea8916fc9d173b114583435a1e7
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-d_w0zttj/wheels/a3/bf/e1/bd9958bb5e4139097b821a36851d307d590aa2093639e077d9
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl size=491070 sha256=9ac49de9affc229fe4d7deaadfdae24e0aac9d161c9f49011c49b1b875ca6cab
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-d_w0zttj/wheels/56/b0/fe/4410d17b32f1f0c3cf54cdfb2bc04d7b4b8f4ae377e2229ba0
Successfully built mock ghp-import future
Installing collected packages: zipp, urllib3, typing-extensions, six, pytz, pyparsing, MarkupSafe, idna, chardet, certifi, sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml, sphinxcontrib-qthelp, sphinxcontrib-jsmath, sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp, sphinxcontrib-devhelp, sphinxcontrib-applehelp, snowballstemmer, requests, PyYAML, python-dateutil, Pygments, packaging, Jinja2, importlib-metadata, imagesize, future, docutils, babel, alabaster, watchdog, sphinx, pyyaml-env-tag, mergedeep, Markdown, ghp-import, commonmark, click, recommonmark, pillow, mock, mkdocs
Successfully installed Jinja2-3.0.1 Markdown-3.3.4 MarkupSafe-2.0.1 PyYAML-5.4.1 Pygments-2.9.0 alabaster-0.7.12 babel-2.9.1 certifi-2021.5.30 chardet-4.0.0 click-8.0.1 commonmark-0.8.1 docutils-0.17.1 future-0.18.2 ghp-import-2.0.1 idna-2.10 imagesize-1.2.0 importlib-metadata-4.6.1 mergedeep-1.3.4 mkdocs-1.2.1 mock-1.0.1 packaging-21.0 pillow-5.4.1 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-dateutil-2.8.1 pytz-2021.1 pyyaml-env-tag-0.1 recommonmark-0.5.0 requests-2.25.1 six-1.16.0 snowballstemmer-2.1.0 sphinx-4.0.3 sphinxcontrib-applehelp-1.0.2 sphinxcontrib-devhelp-1.0.2 sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp-2.0.0 sphinxcontrib-jsmath-1.0.1 sphinxcontrib-qthelp-1.0.3 sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml-1.1.5 typing-extensions-3.10.0.0 urllib3-1.26.6 watchdog-2.1.3 zipp-3.5.0

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:16.926864Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:21.374036Z, duration: 4, exit-code: 0
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/bin/python -m pip install --exists-action=w --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
Collecting mkdocs==1.1.2
  Downloading mkdocs-1.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 MB)
Collecting tornado>=5.0
  Downloading tornado-6.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (428 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=3.3 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (8.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML>=3.10 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.0.1)
Collecting lunr[languages]==0.5.8
  Downloading lunr-0.5.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (2.3 MB)
Collecting livereload>=2.5.1
  Downloading livereload-2.6.3.tar.gz (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Markdown>=3.2.1 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: future>=0.16.0 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from lunr[languages]==0.5.8->mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (0.18.2)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.11.0 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from lunr[languages]==0.5.8->mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (1.16.0)
Collecting nltk>=3.2.5
  Downloading nltk-3.6.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from click>=3.3->mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (4.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (2.0.1)
Collecting joblib
  Downloading joblib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (303 kB)
Collecting regex
  Downloading regex-2021.7.6-cp37-cp37m-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (721 kB)
Collecting tqdm
  Downloading tqdm-4.61.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=3.3->mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions>=3.6.4 in /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from importlib-metadata->click>=3.3->mkdocs==1.1.2->-r requirements.txt (line 1)) (3.10.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: livereload
  Building wheel for livereload (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for livereload (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for livereload: filename=livereload-2.6.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=24726 sha256=046c268e06de06a3bd7df1160fe91c8b00e059d7142ed41dd65e85ef9394991a
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-0rrugzep/wheels/d4/f2/03/55f37093eb8cb0c89d7efb206f792dba55cd5bd67b1c5b1ce1
Successfully built livereload
Installing collected packages: tqdm, regex, joblib, tornado, nltk, lunr, livereload, mkdocs
  Attempting uninstall: mkdocs
    Found existing installation: mkdocs 1.2.1
    Uninstalling mkdocs-1.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled mkdocs-1.2.1
Successfully installed joblib-1.0.1 livereload-2.6.3 lunr-0.5.8 mkdocs-1.1.2 nltk-3.6.2 regex-2021.7.6 tornado-6.1 tqdm-4.61.2

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:21.824634Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:21.888143Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
git rev-parse HEAD
600a315069246da2bb770304f88cadb6ca3d6426

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:22.024845Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:22.093073Z, duration: 0, exit-code: 0
cat mkdocs.yml
docs_dir: docs
extra_css:
- css/custom.css
- https://assets.readthedocs.org/static/css/badge_only.css
- https://assets.readthedocs.org/static/css/readthedocs-doc-embed.css
extra_javascript:
- readthedocs-data.js
- https://assets.readthedocs.org/static/core/js/readthedocs-doc-embed.js
- https://assets.readthedocs.org/static/javascript/readthedocs-analytics.js
google_analytics: null
markdown_extensions:
- meta
- admonition
- footnotes
- attr_list
- toc
- sane_lists
pages:
- Getting Started:
  - Overview: index.md
  - What's New?: new.md
  - Important Reads: prerequisites.md
  - Installation: installation.md
  - Support/Bugreport: support.md
- Faceit Create:
  - Prepare Geometry: prepare.md
  - Setup: setup.md
  - Landmarks: landmarks.md
  - Rigging: rigging.md
  - Expressions: expressions.md
  - Bake: bake.md
  - Utilities: utils.md
  - Export: export.md
  - Tips and Tricks: tips.md
  - FBX Retargeting: fbx_retargeting.md
- ARKit MOCAP:
  - ARKit Overview: arkit_shapes.md
  - Setup: arkit_setup.md
  - Control Rig: control_rig.md
  - Mocap: mocap_utils.md
  - Face Cap App: face_cap_utils.md
  - Live Link Face: epic_utils.md
- Other:
  - Changelog: log.md
  - FAQ: FAQ.md
site_author: Fynn Braren
site_description: Faceit - Auto-Rig IPhoneX Shape Keys (Blendshapes) - Performance
  Capture for ANY Character!
site_name: Faceit Documentation
site_url: https://faceit-doc.readthedocs.io
theme:
  collapse_navigation: true
  custom_dir: overrides
  include_sidebar: true
  name: readthedocs
  prev_next_buttons_location: none
  sticky_navigation: false

[rtd-command-info] start-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:22.241233Z, end-time: 2021-07-08T14:57:23.269100Z, duration: 1, exit-code: 0
/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/envs/v2/bin/python -m mkdocs build --clean --site-dir _build/html --config-file mkdocs.yml
WARNING -  Config value: 'pages'. Warning: The 'pages' configuration option has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release of MkDocs. Use 'nav' instead. 
INFO    -  Cleaning site directory 
INFO    -  Building documentation to the directory: /home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/faceit-doc/checkouts/v2/_build/html 
WARNING -  Documentation file 'FAQ.md' contains a link to 'hardware.md' which is not found in the documentation files. 
WARNING -  Documentation file 'epic_utils.md' contains a link to 'img/mocap/epic/epic_ui.jpg' which is not found in the documentation files. 
WARNING -  Documentation file 'prepare.md' contains a link to 'capture.md' which is not found in the documentation files. 
INFO    -  Documentation built-in 0.48 seconds
```

Comment: I would suggest that you open a pull request with the [sphinx_rtd_theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/) project with the analogue you desire, else fork the project, implement the fix you want, then release your fork.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I was able to solve it by customizing the theme. I was just looking in the wrong places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this after some more research.
The reason why it didn't work was because I didn't place the

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

in the main.html file.

All necessary information can be found here:
https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/customizing-your-theme/#using-the-theme-custom_dir

Answer (score 1):

To add any custom script to Mkdocs generated  blocks, here is what worked for me as recommended in the answer above and in the Material/mkdocs here: https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/customization/#overriding-blocks

I needed to integrate the marker.io widget to my mkdocs generated site by using the marker.io manual install method which adds a script to the HEAD tag.

1. overrides/main.html (The theme template file that you need to customize)
2. Make sure you extend the base template and override the 'site_meta' tag.
3. Use super() to ensure whatever was prior plugged in, stays and you don't overwrite that.

Mkdocs/docs/overrides/ dir

```html
---main.html---

    {% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block announce %}
    <div class="an_announcement">Some of the announcement that we'd like to show in the theme on all pages.</div>
    {% endblock %}

    {% block site_meta %}
    <!-- Add scripts that need to run before here -->
    {{ super() }}
    <!-- Add scripts that need to run afterward here -->

    <!-- Marker.io feedback tool for Arcana Documentation -->
    <script>
      window.markerConfig = {
        project: '<your marker.io Project ID', 
        source: 'snippet'
      };
    </script>
  
    <script>
    !function(e,r,a){if(!e.__M.......(window,document); 

    //snipped marker.io script just to give you the idea 
    //see https://help.marker.io/en/articles/4667238-widget-installation-methods#h_13f1da8aac for details

    </script>

    {% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps!